# How do I make make my code repeat itself?

Tags: java, if-statement

```
public Action getMove(CritterInfo info) {
      count++;
      Direction d = info.getDirection();
      if (count < 100) {   
         if (info.getFront() == Neighbor.OTHER) {
            return Action.INFECT;
         } else {
            return Action.RIGHT;
         }
      }
      if (count >= 100) {
         if (info.getFront() == Neighbor.OTHER) {
            return Action.INFECT;
         } else if (count / 100.0 < 2.0 && count / 100.0 >= 1.0 && !(d == Direction.EAST)) {
            return Action.LEFT;
         } else if (count / 100.0 < 3.0 && count / 100.0 >= 2.0 && !(d == Direction.WEST)) {
            return Action.RIGHT; 
         } else {
            return Action.HOP;
         }
      }
      return Action.INFECT;
   }
```

Right now I have this code that is part of my critter and i'm having problems are the `if (count >= 100)` part of the code. I can't get my go east and go west code to repeat itself because when I divide count by 100.0, it only works up until 299 then it just stays going west running into the wall. I've tried to set an else if statement after my go west code stating

```
} else if (count == 299) {
       count = 0;
}
```

but this didn't solve my problem either. Any ideas? I just want my critter to sweep east and west over and over again.

Comment: A trivial (and probably useless) answer will be "you can repeat yourself with a `while` loop`". However, your actual intent is unclear, we need more context to provide an actual useful answer.

Comment: Trivial or not, it seems like you need a `do-while` loop.

Comment: It looks strange that you use floating point type for counter

Comment: `count` ois incremented for each _Move_, even when it is a _Hop_ or _Infect_, And you use `count` to compute a change in direction. Since you are talking about a _wall_, is it possible you try to detect when you touch the _wall_ and then change direction **with** the `count` information? Am I correct?

Comment: all im trying to do is make it so that it goes east at count 100 to 199 then it goes west from 200 to 299 then it goes back west from 300 to 399 and so on and so forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use variables instead of your numbers, and change them each time their numbers are reached.Then you can create a method that changes the direction each time the number reaches 100+(100*n).
So, if you reach 200, it will check that the condition I set above is true and will therefore change directions for the next 100 numbers.
Was this what you were looking for , or did I misunderstand what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some kind of "cyclic" function like *modulo* (`%`) instead of the absolute value of `count`. E.g.

```
public Action getMove(CritterInfo info) {
    count++;
    Direction d = info.getDirection();

    if (count < 100) {   
         if (info.getFront() == Neighbor.OTHER) {
            return Action.INFECT;
         } else {
            return Action.RIGHT;
         }
     } 
     else {   
        int choiceOfAction = (count - 100)%200;
        if (0 <= choiceOfDir && choiceOfDir < 100 && !(d == Direction.EAST)) {
            return Action.LEFT;
        } else if (100 <= choiceOfDir && choiceOfDir < 200  && !(d == Direction.WEST)) {
            return Action.RIGHT; 
        } else {
            return Action.HOP;
        }
    }
}
```

The line `int choiceOfAction = (count - 100)%200;` will yield a value of `choiceOfAction` with:

- if `count` is in [100, 200[ : `choiceOfAction` is in [0, 100[
- if `count` is in [200, 300[ : `choiceOfAction` is in [100, 200[
- if `count` is in [300, 400[ : `choiceOfAction` is in [0, 100[
- etc.

Note that I removed the last `return` in your method that was never reached, and also, that in the case above you will `HOP` only when you reach the limit and change direction.